# How to access system properties passed with -D switch in maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml, android-uiautomator

I am using android-maven-plugin for writing uiautomator test cases. My project works for different clients and I need to send the client's name as string to the program, so that the selected cleint's app is tested. Here is the code which is expecting client's name

```
@Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        UiAutomatorUtils.unlockEmulator();
        String launcherString = /* NEEDED A WAY TO ACCESS CLIENT'S NAME STRING" */
        assertNotNull("launcherString not provided", launcherString);
        AppLauncher.launchApplicationFromDesiredLauncher(launcherString);
        UiAutomatorUtils.setCurrentTestName("LoginLogout");
    }
```

How can I achieve this.
I tried to pass the argument from command line like this: mvn install -DLAUNCHER=xyzClient
and get the value in the setUp() with System.getProperty("LAUNCHER"). But it is not working.

I want to know what is the best approach for this challenge?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is not a good practice for your test case to pull such a dynamic value from outside. I will not know how to build your maven project if such property is required to be specified.

I don't fully understand the context, but probably you can put the list of client names in your test resources and run against it. In this way everything will always be tested by any developers who are checking the code out. When you release the project, you can also be sure that all of the clients has been tested.